# Protobuf data in HTTP request

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm using a program that sends HTTP requests to the Spotify API using `application/x-protobuf` as Content-Type:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-protobuf
User-Agent: Spotify/113500458 Win32/0 (PC laptop)
Accept-Language: en
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 134

0A 4D 0A 20 36 35 62 37 30 38 30 37 33 66 63 30 |  M  65b708073fc0
34 38 30 65 61 39 32 61 30 37 37 32 33 33 63 61 | 480ea92a077233ca
38 37 62 64 12 29 53 2D 31 2D 35 2D 32 31 2D 37 | 87bd )S-1-5-21-7
39 33 32 33 31 30 32 38 33 2D 30 37 30 35 31 31 | 932310283-070511
38 35 38 32 2D 37 36 37 32 36 37 33 34 35 30 AA | 8582-7672673450ª
06 34 0A 0A 66 69 73 6C 64 70 65 75 74 65 12 09 |  4  fisldpeute    
67 70 73 73 65 70 75 74 65 1A 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B | gpssepute       
1B 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B |                 
1B 1B 1B 1B 1B 1B                               |
```

How can I please decode that? How does it work and how can I "achieve the same"?

My goal would be to reproduce the request by editing some info in the data it sends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decode it (or write the same kind of message) with any protobuf serializer. However, unlike things like XML/JSON, protobuf doesn't include things like field names in the payload, just numeric tokens (field numbers). The *best* thing to do is to ask "is the .proto schema for this available?". If not, you can still do it, but some of the data types are ambiguous (meaning: two different values can, depending on the schemas, be the exact same bytes) - so a little inspired guesswork is requird. You can reverse-engineer a .proto schema relatively easily, though, using tools like https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode (I must go and fix the regex there, so you can paste your input including the spaces!)

---

my guess at that schema

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
message SomeRoot {
    Header header = 1;
    Body body = 101;
}
message Header {
    string id = 1; // example "65b708073fc0480e..."
    string ref = 2; // example "S-1-5-21-7932310..."
}
message Body {
    string Foo = 1; // example "fisldpeute"
    string Bar = 2; // example "gpssepute"
    bytes Blap = 3; // example 1B1B1B1B1B...? some metadata?
}
```

based on:

[image: this decoding]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I in fact found your website when doing my researches, I'd appreciate it if you could fix the RegEx as I was unable to use it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sofia it is just complaining about the spaces; make it a contiguous chunk of hex and it should work. I'll fix that ASAP, though

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. However, I'm lacking a lot of knowledge on Protobuf and don't think I'll be able to reproduce the request, RIP

Comment: @Sofia I've posted a guess at the schema

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. What you're calling "foo" and "bar" are actually a username and password. I guess I'll use your website to generate C# code (I do C# so that's probably the best to do) from this schema and try guessing what I can do with it next.

Comment: @Sofia fair enough; just add a package-reference to `protobuf-net` (from NuGet), then: `var obj = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<SomeRoot>(yourPayload);` - done; as you can probably guess: feel free to change those names - every name there is a complete guess

Comment: Thank you. You helped me understand a lot and I now believe I'm going to be able to achieve my initial goal. Much love